# How to use an UIWebView to show small offline html documents?

Tags: iphone, uiwebview

Could I ship my app with an html document and display this using a UIWebView? How hard is this to use?

Is it possible to have a small frame with the UIWebView inside, or does it always take up the whole screen? And can I get rid of all those controls, so the UIWebView works like an advanced UILabel or UITextView?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes; it's easy; you can have a small embedded webview; yes, a naked web view has no controls.

In your `loadView` or `viewDidLoad` method:

```
UIWebView *webview = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(...)];
[self.view addSubview:webview];
NSURL *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"foo" withExtension:@"html"];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[webview loadRequest:request];
[webview release];
```

This will load a foo.html file that you add to your project as a resource.  Alternatively, you can use the `loadHTMLString:baseURL:` if you want to build up the HTML in code.

Comment: I would just add the html file like any other resource - i.e. images, right? or would I have to copy that over to the documents dir after app install? (guess thats only when i would want to edit it)

Comment: `[NSBundle URLForResource:withExtension:]` gives you the path URL for resources in your app bundle, the same as images you add to the Xcode project.  You'll need to get the path in a different way if you want a file in the documents directory.